# "error: no commands supplied" when using distutils.core

Tags: python, distutils

I am using Python 3 on CentOS 7.  I am trying to build a C extension as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html).  I have written a simple program, demo.c, which is in a directory in PYTHONPATH.  demo.c has the following form.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello from demo.c\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs without error.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('demo',
                sources = ['demo.c'])
```

However, the following code

```
setup (name = 'PackageName',
   version = '1.0',
   description = 'This is a demo package',
   ext_modules = [module1])
```

produces the following error.

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: usage: CInterface.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2     [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: CInterface.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: CInterface.py --help-commands
or: CInterface.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying you'll need to pass in a Distutils command, such as `build` [(or probably `build_ext` in your case)](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-source-files).

```
python CInterface.py build_ext
```